# Exposing nodes in a generic binary search tree implementation to visitor pattern

Tags: c#, design, generics

It's common to implement [binary search trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) with an internal `Node` class

```
public class BinarySearchTree<TKey, TVal>
{
    class Node
    {
        public readonly TKey Key;
        public readonly TVal Val;

        public Node Left, Right;

        public Node(TKey key, TVal val, Node left = null, Node right = null) 
        {
            Key = key; Val = val; Left = left; Right = right;
        }
    }

    private Node treeRoot;
}
```

This is nice because it hides client code from being able to directly modify the tree.

It might be the case, however, that we want to expose traversal of the tree (e.g. for printing). In this sense, it might make sense to pull the `Node` class out of `BinarySearchTree`, and redesign `Node` to use the [visitor design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

```
interface ITreeVisitor<TKey, TVal>
{
    void Visit(Node<TKey, TVal> node);
}

class InOrderTreeVisitor<TKey, TVal> : ITreeVisitor<TKey, TVal>
{
    public void Visit(Node<TKey, TVal> node)
    {
        if (node == null) return;

        node.Left.Accept(this);
        // do something to node
        node.Right.Accept(this);
    }
}

public class Node<TKey, TVal>
{
    public Node<TKey, TVal> Left
    {
        get;
        internal set;
    }

    public Node<TKey, TVal> Right
    {
        get;
        internal set;
    }

    public readonly TKey Key;
    public readonly TVal Val;

    public Node(TKey key, TVal val, Node<TKey, TVal> left = null, Node<TKey, TVal> right = null)
    {
        Key = key; Val = val; Left = left; Right = right;
    }

    public void Accept(ITreeVisitor<TKey, TVal> v)
    {
        v.Visit(this);
    }
}

public class BinarySearchTree<TKey, TVal>
{
    public Node<TKey, TVal> Root
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
}
```

The trouble with this is that the visitors have to be generic. This doesn't really make sense. A visitor isn't a container, and doesn't really need to know anything about keys or values.

Is there any way to make `ITreeVisitor` non-generic?

Comment: I think you're suffering from some misconception if you believe it only makes sense for containers to be generic. It looks like you're trying to solve a problem that doesn't actually exist.

Comment: @Doval You think a generic visitor makes sense here, even though nothing is really done with the `Key` and `Val` properties?

Comment: If you ever plan on doing more than just calling ToString, yes. The current approach lets you do more useful things with the contents of the tree than just generic object operations.

Answer (score 3):

In your case the visitor does not need to be concerned with the generic type because it is dealing directly with the node and not invoking any type-specific logic (i.e. `ToString()` should be sufficient).

You have two options:

1. Stick with a generic type and use the proper key and value types each time you create your visitor object.
2. Create a second visitor interface and implementation that are non-generic. You would then inherit from one or the other depending on whether the specific visitor deals with node's data or just the node.

The tradeoff is being more verbose when creating objects, or being more verbose with redundant interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

Override the `ToString()` method in your Node class, and then use a non-generic Visitor to gather the results of calling `ToString()` on each Node.